# Solaris 10 - How to view limits for a given process

Tags: limits, solaris-10

In linux, I can do the following:

```
ps -ef | grep <some process>

<some user>  4847  1864   0   Oct 13 ?          28:45 <some program>
```

Then I can find out what limits are applied by viewing the following file:

```
cat /proc/4847/limits
```

Is there a way to do the same in Solaris 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `plimit` command:

```
$ plimit 4350
4350:   ksh -o vi
   resource              current         maximum
  time(seconds)         unlimited       unlimited
  file(blocks)          unlimited       unlimited
  data(kbytes)          unlimited       unlimited
  stack(kbytes)         8192            unlimited
  coredump(blocks)      unlimited       unlimited
  nofiles(descriptors)  256             65536
  vmemory(kbytes)       unlimited       unlimited
```

Comment: An alternative way: `pfiles 23745 | grep rlimit`

Comment: @MarianoPaniga That would only give the `nofiles` limit, not the full set like the OP Linux way.